# Группировка данных

Tags: python, json, csv

Только недавно начал изучать работу с csv форматом, поэтому не судите строго.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сгруппировать данные JSON и преобразовать результат в csv:

1. Чтобы из вот такого формата(указан формат csv, в командной строке результат выводится не в полном объеме):[image: результат выполнения кода]
2. Получить такую таблицу(сверху группировка по городам, слева - по рандомным группам вконтакте, в ячейках таблицы - количество подписчиков из заданного города):[image: Результат в формате csv]
   Помогите, пожалуйста, искал информацию во многих источниках, но,к сожалению ничего стоящего не нашел. В документации тоже не смог разобраться...
   Буду очень признателен!
   Исходник:

```
import auth_vk
import pandas as pd
from pandas import json_normalize
import csv
import json


V = '9.95' # Версия VK API

session = auth_vk.auth_vk_token()
api = vk.API(session, v=V)

def main():

    y = api.groups.getMembers(group_id='rhymes', fields='city') # Id группы
    data = y
    json_str = json.dumps(data)
    resp = json.loads(json_str)
    data_items = str(resp['items'])
    df = json_normalize(resp['items'])
    df.to_csv(r'./out.csv', index=False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

| id | first.nane | last.nane | can_access_closed | is.closed | city.id | city.title |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 71570 | Денис | Сахарных | True | False | 60.0 | Казань |
| 2529981 | Валентин | Шихобалов | True | False | 60.0 | Казань |
| 327738 | Алеся | Тванченко | False | True | 1.0 | Москва |
| 565215 | Дина | Арзамасцева | True | False | 60.0 | Казань |
| 668848 | Алексей | Журавлев | True | False | 60.0 | Казань |
| 691681 | Евгений | Сироткин | True | False | 88.0 | Набережные Челны |
| 864321 | Андрей | Петухов | True | False | 60.0 | Казань |
| 1884663 | Илья | Быков | False | True | 60.0 | Казань |
| 1273782 | Гузель | Габдрахманова | True | False | 60.0 | Казань |
| 1411877 | Сергей | Куранов | True | False | 60.0 | Казань |
| 1446899 | Мария | Рождественская | True | False |  |  |
| 1864565 | Дмитрий | Спиридонов | True | False | 60.0 | Казань |
| 1888272 | Юлька | Коновалова | True | False | 270.0 | Подольск |
| 1889456 | Алсу | Ситдикова | True | False | 60.0 | Казань |
| 2671147 | Станислав | Каракулов | True | False |  |  |
| 2112346 | Альбина | Мингазова | False | True | 60.0 | Казань |
| 2138689 | Виктория | Черкесова | True | False | 60.0 | Казань |
| 2146532 | Андрей | Кузнецов | True | False | 60.0 | Казань |
| 2222857 | Юлия | Серегина | True | False | 60.0 | Казань |
| 2241785 | Оля | Карлова | True | False |  |  |
| 2262812 | Гона | Коган | True | False | 60.0 | Казань |
| 2327792 | Тимур | Камалетдинов | True | False | 60.0 | Казань |
| 2416133 | Марианна | Итанчаева | False | True | 60.0 | Казань |
| 2477628 | Марсель | Миндубаев | False | True |  |  |

```
"id","first.nane","last.nane","can_access_closed","is.closed","city.id","city.title"
71570,"Денис","Сахарных","True","False",60.0,"Казань"
2529981,"Валентин","Шихобалов","True","False",60.0,"Казань"
327738,"Алеся","Тванченко","False","True",1.0,"Москва"
565215,"Дина","Арзамасцева","True","False",60.0,"Казань"
668848,"Алексей","Журавлев","True","False",60.0,"Казань"
691681,"Евгений","Сироткин","True","False",88.0,"Набережные Челны"
864321,"Андрей","Петухов","True","False",60.0,"Казань"
1884663,"Илья","Быков","False","True",60.0,"Казань"
1273782,"Гузель","Габдрахманова","True","False",60.0,"Казань"
1411877,"Сергей","Куранов","True","False",60.0,"Казань"
1446899,"Мария","Рождественская","True","False",,
1864565,"Дмитрий","Спиридонов","True","False",60.0,"Казань"
1888272,"Юлька","Коновалова","True","False",270.0,"Подольск"
1889456,"Алсу","Ситдикова","True","False",60.0,"Казань"
2671147,"Станислав","Каракулов","True","False",,
2112346,"Альбина","Мингазова","False","True",60.0,"Казань"
2138689,"Виктория","Черкесова","True","False",60.0,"Казань"
2146532,"Андрей","Кузнецов","True","False",60.0,"Казань"
2222857,"Юлия","Серегина","True","False",60.0,"Казань"
2241785,"Оля","Карлова","True","False",,
2262812,"Гона","Коган","True","False",60.0,"Казань"
2327792,"Тимур","Камалетдинов","True","False",60.0,"Казань"
2416133,"Марианна","Итанчаева","False","True",60.0,"Казань"
2477628,"Марсель","Миндубаев","False","True",,
```

Comment: На картинке csv а ие JSON.

Comment: Да, знаю, в строке кода df = json_normalize(resp['items']) такой же вывод, сделал скрин csv файла, чтобы полностью вывести результат, а то в командной строке он выводится не полностью(

Comment: Стесняюсь спросить, а что Вам дает конвертация в из списка словарей в json и обратно? Мне почему-то кажется что как минимум 3 строчки кода здесь лишние и можно записать как `resp = api.groups.getMembers(group_id='rhymes', fields='city')` или я что-то упускаю?

Comment: Более того, возьмусь предположить, что `df = pd.DataFrame(api.groups.getMembers(group_id='rhymes', fields='city'))` отработает корректно

Comment: И последнее, судя по картинкам речь идет не о сортировке, а о группировке данных а точнее о создании сводной таблицы. Поскольку в тех образцах, кторые Вы предоставили, данные ни коим образом не сопоставимы и предположить какой результат вам действительно нужен возьмется разве что какй нибудь "кармодрочер камикадзе", то без описания логики преобразования данных хотябы на словах вы рискуете долго прождать ответа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну для примера, просто табличный вывод, который при желанний можно записать в файл

```
from prettytable import from_csv

with open("myfile.csv", encoding='utf-8') as fp:
    mytable = from_csv(fp)
print(mytable)

+---------+------------+-----------+-------------------+-----------+---------+------------+
|    id   | first.nane | last.nane | can_access_closed | is.closed | city.id | city.title |
+---------+------------+-----------+-------------------+-----------+---------+------------+
|  71570  |   Денис    |  Сахарных |        True       |   False   |   60.0  |   Казань   |
| 2529981 |  Валентин  | Шихобалов |        True       |   False   |   1.0   |   Казань   |
....
| 2416133 |  Марианна  | Итанчаева |       False       |    True   |   60.0  |   Казань   |
| 2477628 |  Марсель   | Миндубаев |       False       |    True   |         |            |
+---------+------------+-----------+-------------------+-----------+---------+------------+
```

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, а как можно пересчитать количество повторений названий городов?

Comment: 'а как можно пересчитать количество повторений названий городов?" Используйуте pandas он и сoздовался для обработки и анализа данных.